Error starting up Eureka Client with Spring Boot 3.3.3
I am developing an application using Spring Boot 3.3.3 and Java21. While starting the server i am facing this issue
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:288) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:469) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:257) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:202) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:990) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:628) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at com.seqnc.ThirdyPartyDataServicesApplication.main(ThirdyPartyDataServicesApplication.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.getApplications()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient()" is null
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:89) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

This issue is coming up only when i include this XERO dependency
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.xeroapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>xero-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.16.0</version>
        </dependency>

Here is my dependency tree for XERO-API
[INFO] +- com.github.xeroapi:xero-java:jar:4.16.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.auth0:java-jwt:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.auth0:jwks-rsa:jar:0.17.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:jar:17.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.joschi.jackson:jackson-datatype-threetenbp:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:3.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:3.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:jar:3.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:3.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:3.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.brsanthu:migbase64:jar:2.2:compile

When i am using Java11 and springboot 2.3.1 this issue is not there, after upgrading to Java21 and springboot3.3.3 only this issue coming up.
Is there any way to handle this issue? or do I need to exclude any dependencies from XERO-API?
Thank you

(1) Spring Boot 3.3 use jakarta.xxx not javax.xxx. (2) Your dependency tree for XERO-API, have javax.xxxxx (3) Change xero-java 4.16.0 to xero-java 8.3.0, 8.3.0 can support jakarta.servlet-api 6.0.0.
